# Have trouble understanding wpf visual studio setup

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have a wpf project setup by visual studio. I'm trying to create MVP classes, but I cannot access any xaml properties in these classes that I've created (e.g. textBox1.text or label.Content)

Files they gave me were MainWindow.xaml.cs, MainWindow.xaml and some other files. I can access those xaml properties in MainWindow.xaml.cs. But in my view.cs it show `'textBox' does not exist in the current content`. Appreciate any extra details and info

MainWIndow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace myApp
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Model model;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //initialize the storage
        model= new Model();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// clear the textbox for user input
    /// </summary>
    private void clearInput()
    {
        textBox1.Text = ""; //these works fine
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
    }

[...]
}
```

view.cs:

```
namespace myApp
{
public interface IView
{
    void clearInput();
}

public class PView: IView
{
    public void clearInput()
    {
        textBox1.Text = ""; //error
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would guess that you'll need to do additional work and reading to understand what you need to do (out of the box, the XAML and cs files are not going to be set up for MVP, MVC, MVVM, or anything else). Not sure if this will help given how old it is: [Using the Model-View-Presenter (MVP) Design Pattern to enable Presentational Interoperability and Increased Testability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jowardel/2008/09/09/using-the-model-view-presenter-mvp-design-pattern-to-enable-presentational-interoperability-and-increased-testability/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the controls (TextBox etc) in your XAML file a name, like this

```
<TextBlock Name="textblock1" .....
```

Then in your code file you can access textblock1

**EDIT**

However, these controls are allways private, so not visible to other classes. To make the data public you need to try something like this:

```
public string TextBlockText
{
   get { return textblock1.Text; }
}
```

And then in your other classes you can use

```
var text = MainWindow.TextBlockText;
```

**EDIT2**

Alternatively, you can make these controls public like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

Comment: yea I have that, that's why I can access them in the mainwindow.xaml.cs. But I cant access them in view.cs that I've created

Comment: So I have to create these methods in my MainWindow.xaml.cs in order for view class to access it? It seems messy. Maybe I didnt word my question properly, I did an edit, can you take a look? thanks

Comment: yup, you shouldnt access controls in your XAML from another class. If you want to implement MVP you need to create these accessor properties. Why not try moving to MVVM, its the way most WPF is done, partially for this reason. Howe3ver, I have added an edit to show the work-around you need

Comment: oh no wonder, has something to do with `<Window x:Class="reportingApp.MainWindow"` right?
Now I get why I only see people suggesting MVVM now. Thanks!! I will take a look at that. So I guess mainwindow.xaml.cs will be my VM, where my click even function and everything is in?

Comment: definitely. Take a look at simple MVVM implementation to start with, If you must do MVP see the additional edit to my answer

Comment: @user308553  (from what I've used and how I've seen it suggested) the .xaml.cs generally only would include the minimal code-behind required (generally *none* other than the auto-generate initialization), and your view model would be a separate class and use bindings and data context to communicate with the xaml.